# Why does scrolling in Emacs become so slow when a file has more than 2000 lines?

Tags: emacs, scroll, font-lock

I have some files which are more than 2000 lines. It's very painful to edit these files because editing will become very slow and so does scrolling (scroll up, scroll down, page up, page down).

I have tried to solve this problem based on the following posts on EmacsWiki:

- [Font Lock Speed](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontLockSpeed)
- [Smooth Scrolling](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmoothScrolling)

but I still have the same problem. Could anybody help me?

Here is some more information that might be of interest:

- Emacs version: 24.3 on Ubuntu 13.04
- `erlang-mode` version: `erlang-20130912` from MELPA, Erlang: R16B01
- I use: `erlang-mode`, `outline-minor-mode`, `auto-complete`, `flymake`, `distel-mode`, `prelude-mode`, `helm-mode`, `projectile-mode`, `linum-mode`
- If I turn off `font-lock-mode`, it will speed up but I lose syntax highlighting.
- I have tried editing the `lib_event` source file `http.c` which has 4000 lines, and the speed is quick, I just wonder why editing my Erlang source file is so slow. Maybe it's because I use level 4 syntax highlighting for Erlang; if I use level 2 or level 3 it will be faster. So, I still think it's the font-lock problem because `c-mode` syntax highlighting is less complicated than syntax highlighting in `erlang-mode`.
- There might also be a problem in `erlang-mode`: I found that when I page-down or up, it will read and write to the disk which is very weird.

Comment: It's important to state which mode the files are (i.e. C++ / org-mode ... ). In any case,
`find-file-literally` will always work.

Comment: I don't think it should be that slow. You can use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to report it if you think it's a bug.

Comment: I've seen problems of this nature with certain major modes and linum-mode.  If you are using linum-mode, try disabling it to see if that fixes the slow down.

Comment: One of Emacs's own source files has 20 thousand lines, so I can assure you that Emacs has no such "2 thousand lines" limit.  IOW the problem has to be triggered by a specific kind of file, or by some local configuration.

Comment: @Stefan Yes,I tried the lib_event source file http.c, which has 4 thousand lines,and the speed is quick,I just wonder why my erlang source file is so slow.Maybe it's because I use the level 4 syntax highlight in erlang,if I use level 2,or level 3 it will be faster. So,I still think it's the font-lock problem. Maybe there is also some problem in erlang-mode ,i found when I page-down or up ,it will read and write the disk which is very weird.

Comment: Might be a performance problem in erlang-mode, indeed.  Contact the authors to figure it out.

Comment: Try running emacs with -q option, then:

1. Load the file and try scrolling.

Still slow?

2. Load the file, set the file in fundamental mode.

Still slow?

If #2 was still slow, then it is indeed your emacs.

If #1 was slow, but not #2, then it is the mode.

If #2 and #1 is slow, then it is some configuration you have